# Suppose X = number of rolls of a 4 - sided, fair die (i.e. faces labeled 1 - 4) until a 2 turns up. Calculate the probability that X is 2 or more

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

This is a negative binomial distribution. How would you solve this equation?

Answer (score 3):

It could also be answered using a geometric distribution (which is a special case of the NB distribution). Using the definition that $X$ is the number of Bernoulli trials until one success (i.e. rolling a 2 is a success, not 2 is a failure), then the cumulative density function of $X$ is:

$P(X \le k) = 1-(1-p)^k$ (for $k \ge 1$)

We are interested in $P(X\ge k)$. Rearranging,

$P(X\ge k)=P(X>k-1)=1-P(X\le k-1)=(1-p)^{k-1}$

In this case, we need to plug in $k=2$ and $p=1/4$.

Comment: If you're going to use the geometric distribution wouldn't the formula be p(1−)−1 ? why did you take out the first p in the outside of the parentheses?

Comment: Are you referring the to PMF, i.e. $P(X=k)$? I am referring to the CDF, which is $P(X\le k)$